# How to make a custom status command Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tried to make a custom discord status command and it is working but printing out and setting the bots status to ('args',) with args being what is entered by the user

This is what the current lines of code are for the command:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The Bot is now Online")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity= discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.listening, name = 'To the server'))


@bot.command()
async def Status(ctx, *args):
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity= discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.listening, name = f'{args}'))  
        await ctx.send(args) 
        print(args)
```

This prints out in the console, sends to the discord channel and sets the bots status as ('args',) so if I was to do the command *.Status Hey* it would set it to ('Hey',)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple typo. You put `*args` when you really need `*, args`.

Instead of:

```py
@bot.command()
async def Status(ctx, *args):
```

Do:

```py
@bot.command()
async def Status(ctx, *, args):
```

Your code would look something like this.

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import discord

bot = Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The Bot is now Online")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity= discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.listening, name = 'To the server'))


@bot.command()
async def Status(ctx, *, args):
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity= discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.listening, name = f'{args}'))  
        await ctx.send(args) 
        print(args)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

An interaction between you and the bot would go

> You: !Status Something

> Bot: Something
>
> Bot sets its status to "Something"